# PHP - Call PHP file in a DIV

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I'm having an issue with a AJAX code, I've near to none experirence with this language, the issue is, I'm trying to call a PHP file "prepare_game.php":

**prepare_game.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
include "config.php";
if(isset($_SESSION["user_name"]))
{
$selectcategoria = "SELECT DISTINCT id_partida, id_categoria FROM partida WHERE user_name =".$_SESSION["user_name"];
$querycategoria = mysqli_query($con, $selectcategoria);
$rowcategoria = mysqli_fetch_array($querycategoria);
$personajenum = rand(0,23);
$selectpersonaje = "SELECT nombre_personaje, foto_personaje FROM Categoria WHERE id_personaje =".$personajenum;
$querypersonaje = mysqli_query($selectpersonaje);
$rowpersonaje = mysqli_fetch_array($querypersonaje);
$selectturno = "SELECT user_name_retador, user_name_oponente FROM WHERE user_name =".$_SESSION["user_name"];
$queryturno = mysqli_query($con, $selectcategoria);
$rowturno = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

if($_SESSION["user_name"]=$rowturno["user_name_oponente"]){
$insertestado = "INSERT INTO estadojugador(id_partida, user_name, turno_activo, personaje_secreto) VALUES(".$row['id_partida'].", ".$_SESSION["user_name"].", "."false".", ".$rowpersonaje["nombre_personaje"].")";
$queryestado = mysqli_query($insertestado);
}
else
{
$insertestado = "INSERT INTO estadojugador(id_partida, user_name, turno_activo, personaje_secreto) VALUES(".$row['id_partida'].", ".$_SESSION["user_name"].", "."true".", ".$rowpersonaje["nombre_personaje"].")";
$queryestado = mysqli_query($insertestado);
}
echo "<img src=\"categorias/".$rowpersonaje["foto_personaje"]."\" width=\"240\" height=\"360\" style=\"display:block; margin: 0 auto;\"></img>";
}

?>
```

As you may see, there's no need for any POST/GET array variables, then I created a JS function that calls this PHP file using an AJAX call.

**prepareGame()**

```
  prepareGame = function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "prepare_game.php"
    }).done(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
```

Then I call the JS function through:

**JS script:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      prepareGame();
</script>
```

However, nothing happens.

**Problem:**

How to call a PHP file, without using form tags, nor use any DATA attributes in the AJAX call?

Notes:

**prepare_game.php** fills two tables in a DB, then it prints an IMG tag through an echo.
**prepare_game.php** loading method must be inside a DIV tag.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<div id="whatever"></div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#whatever').load('prepare_game.php');
    });
</script>
```

This should just take the results from `prepare_game.php` and put them in the `#whatever` div.

Comment: May I call this SCRIPT tag inside the DIV?